# Assigning the value of the output of a function the the input of the function

Tags: python

So I have a function suppose func(x), it returns the value of y. Next, I want to again assign y as x to the process and get a new value y. I want to continue this like 1000 times.
Any suggestions would be beneficial.

so in the code below,
I have tried to make a function that will carry the number of iterations. The second function does the calculation. But I am not being able to connect the two.

```
def increment(num): 
    if num < 1000:
        return num + 1 
    else:
        print("Loop limit exceeded")

       
def square(x): 
    y = x * x
    return y


x = y
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to compute?  Are you trying to square a number 1000 times (which is going to give you a very very large number), or are you trying to square that number plus 1000?  What you describe is very simple (it's called *recursion* and you can look up a lot of examples of it) but it's not obvious how exactly you want to apply it to the two functions in your question.

Comment: Suppose I have x=2, I will get an output of 4. I want to assign this 4 to x, so x = 4. I want to create an iteration that will take the return value and put it back into the function as the new variable.      I just gave the above as an example and to make it easier to understand, the function I am dealing with is more complicated.

Comment: In the title you describe writing a recursive function, that would take its own output and an iteration number as a parameter, but in the description you appear to be describing a much simpler `for` or `while` loop. Is it necessary for your use-case that you use recursion or would looping be an acceptable answer?

Comment: G.Anderson, thanks. Any method is acceptable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what I think you're trying to do, but with a limit of 10 iterations instead of 1000 (because I don't want to make my fans spin up):

```
>>> def func(x, n=0):
...     if n >= 10:
...         return x
...     return func(x * x, n + 1)
...
>>> func(1)
1
>>> func(2)
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

The iterative equivalent is to use a `for` loop over the same range:

```
>>> def func(x):
...     for _ in range(10):
...         x *= x
...     return x
...
>>> func(1)
1
>>> func(2)
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

If the idea is that you're not trying to make `func` itself recursive, and you want to apply it to the same value 1000 times, just call it in a loop:

```
>>> def func(x):
...     return x * x
...
>>> x = 2
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     x = func(x)
...
>>> x
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```